# Applying Boundary Conditions to Particle in a 1D Box

Tags: discrete-mathematics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem

the quantum particle in a 1D box leads to the following eigen equation

$$\varphi_n(\alpha) = A e^{i\lambda \alpha}, \quad \alpha \in [0,2\pi], \ \lambda \in \mathbb C \tag{1}$$

and the boundary condition

$$\varphi_n(0) = \varphi_n(2\pi n), \quad n \in \mathbb Z \tag{2}$$

Now I try to solve for $\lambda$.

I use the B.C. and get $1 = \cos(2\pi n\lambda) + i \sin(2\pi n \lambda)$

which only holds for $\lambda \in \mathbb Z$ so we can just rename $\lambda$ to e.g. $n$ and get our solution

$$\varphi_n(\alpha) = A e^{i n \alpha} \tag{3}$$

Now I wanted to do this a bit more pedantic and tried this:

For $1 = \cos(2\pi n\lambda) + i \sin(2\pi n \lambda)$ to hold, we need

$$2\pi n\lambda = 2 \pi u, \quad u \in \mathbb Z \tag{4}$$

giving us: $n\lambda = u$ giving us $\lambda = \frac{u}{n} \not\in \mathbb Z$ but $\lambda = \frac{u}{n} \in \mathbb Q$.

So I don't really see my mistake here and how I'd do it correctly.

Comment: $1 = \cos(2\pi n\lambda) + i\sin(2\pi n\lambda) \iff \color{red}{n}\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}$, not $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}$.